# On loading, page error in console

Tags: tomcat, servlets, grails

Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context

```
| Error 2017-09-20 12:47:47,593 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR [/xxxx].

[grails-errorhandler]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails-errorhandler threw exception
Message: Error applying layout : XXXX
    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in /grails-app/views/layouts/XXXX.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in     ''
^    745 | run . . . in     ''
Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: could not initialize proxy - no Session
->>  167 | runWorker in /grails-app/views/layouts/XXXX.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
->>  336 | doCall    in XXXXgrails_app_views_layouts_XXXX_main_gsp$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    681 | run       in XXXXgrails_app_views_layouts_XXXX_main_gsp
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2017-09-20 12:47:47,600 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR [Tomcat].[localhost]  - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/grails-errorhandler]
```

While loading a page, the error displays in console repeatedly. 404 error page is there and working correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are accessing data from an entity that needs to lazily load data but you have no Hibernate session opened. Without seeing your .gsp code, it's the most I can say...

Comment: newbie to grails , i tried to get a data from gsp page using hibernate is that a issue